# How to configure Maven to use GWT module sources for compiling but do not include them in final JAR/WAR?

Tags: java, gwt, maven, jar

I have a GWT project and I want to use some other in house GWT libraries as dependencies.

We do not want to include sources in our final build. Most open source GWT libraries include sources in the JAR, but we want to keep sources separate, use them to compile, then throw them away.

Is there a way to do this with Maven?

Comment: Does your code have only UI related stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the scope to `provided`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.you.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Brad's answer will fix the problem in a very narrow scenario. Setting the scope to provided totally avoids the jar from being pushed into War's lib. This is not what you would need in use case of the "lib" on to server side code. This usually happens 
    1) Constants.
    2) DTO's/Beans.
    3) RPC service interfaces
    4) Request Factory proxy declarations

You have to have a mix of approaches.

1) Brad's approach when the "lib" in purely client and has no chance of being used in server clode.

2) Modularize code to have Constants/DTO's/Proxy/RF related interfaces and any such code  in a project that generates two artifact jars.

```
   A) One with classes only - to be used to push stuff in to web-inf/lib i.e scope compile/runtime.

   B) Another with sources/classess - to be used with gwt compilation i.e scope provided.
```

Generating two jars might seem redundant. This is the only sane option i have tried. Keen on check whether there is any other option that will be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kind of library (package in jar file) in GWT:

- Server side library like "gwt-servlet.jar" does not contain source code in jar file and you can add maven dependency like this in your pom:

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
>   <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
>   <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
>   <scope>runtime</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

- Client side library like "gwt-user.jar" which contain source code in jar file, this kind of library does not require to package in your war file and you can add maven dependency like this in your pom:

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
>   <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
>   <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
>   <scope>provided</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

Have a nice time.